# Parsing binary files with Python

Tags: python, binaryfiles

As a side project I would like to try to parse binary files (Mach-O files specifically). I know tools exist for this already (otool) so consider this a learning exercise.

The problem I'm hitting is that I don't understand how to convert the binary elements found into a python representation.  For example, the Mach-O file format starts with a header which is defined by a C Struct.  The first item is a uint_32 'magic number' field.  When i do

```
magic = f.read(4)
```

I get

```
b'\xcf\xfa\xed\xfe'
```

This is starting to make sense to me. It's literally a byte array of 4 bytes.  However I want to treat this like a 4-byte int that represents the original magic number.  Another example is the numberOfSections field. I just want the number represented by 4-byte field, not an array of literal bytes.

Perhaps I'm thinking about this all wrong. Has anybody worked on anything similar?  Do I need to write functions to look these 4-byte byte arrays and shift and combine their values to produce the number I want?  Is endienness going to screw me here?  Any pointers would be most helpful.

Comment: I wrote a code recipe a while back that aims to simplify this syntax. Check it out and see if it helps: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577610-decoding-binary-files/?in=user-4175703

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at the [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module:

```
In [1]: import struct

In [2]: magic = b'\xcf\xfa\xed\xfe'

In [3]: decoded = struct.unpack('<I', magic)[0]

In [4]: hex(decoded)
Out[4]: '0xfeedfacf'
```

Answer (score 13):

There's [Kaitai Struct project](http://kaitai.io/) that solves exactly that problem. First, you describe a certain file format using a .ksy spec, then you compile it into a Python library (or, actually, a library in any other major programming language), `import` it, and, voila, parsing boils down to:

```
from mach_o import MachO
my_file = MachO.from_file("/path/to/your/file")
my_file.magic # => 0xfeedface
my_file.num_of_sections # => some other integer
my_file.sections # => list of objects that represent sections
```

They have a [growing repository of file format specs](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct_formats). It doesn't have Mach-O file format spec (yet?), but there are complex formats like Java `.class` or Microsoft's PE executable described there, so I guess it shouldn't be a major problem to write spec for Mach-O format as well.

It is actually better than [Construct](http://construct.readthedocs.io) or [Hachoir](https://github.com/vstinner/hachoir), because it's compiled (as opposed to interpreted), thus it's faster, and it includes tons of other helpful tools like visualizer or format diagram maker. For example, this is a generated explanation diagram for PE executable format:

[image: PE executable format]

Comment: The Construct docs contain a [comparison](http://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compilation.html#comparison-with-kaitai-struct) of the two. Kaitai is faster, but it's a pretty big downside (IMO) that Kaitai doesn't yet support _building_ structs, only parsing. So I wouldn’t call one “better” than the other.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest the [`Construct`](http://construct.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) module. It offers a very high level interface.